# Tensorflow Tensorboard default port

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

Is there a way to change the default port (`6006`) on TensorBoard so we could open multiple TensorBoards? Maybe an option like `--port="8008"`?

Comment: look at the asker and answerer, he wanted to add the information

Comment: @etarion your link is currently broken (or at least not public)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

In fact there is an option to change the default port ...

```
tensorboard --logdir=/tmp  --port=8008
```

Answer (score 30):

You should provide a port flag (`--port=6007`).

But I am here to explain how you can find it and other flags without any documentation. Almost all command line tools have a flag `-h` or `--help` which shows all possible flags this tool allows.

By running it you will see information about a port flag and that `--logdir` allows you to

> also pass a comma separated list of log directories

and you can also inspect separate event-files and tags with `--event_file` and `--tag` flags

Comment: Some versions of TensorBoard apparently didn't support the "help" flags: [see this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/936)

Answer (score 13):

If you are already in the directory where TensorFlow writes its logs, you should specify the port first:

```
tensorboard --port=6007 --logdir runs
```

If you are feeding a directory to `logdir`, then the order doesn't matter. (I am using TensorBaord 1.8)